# Pytest test failing when run with other tests but passes when run by itself

Tags: python, django, pytest, channel

I very basic test that checks if a user that is not logged in can connect to my websocket that is as follows:

```
@pytest.mark.asyncio
async def test_unauthenticated_cant_connect_to_websocket(unauthenticated_websocket_communicator: WebsocketCommunicator):
    connected, subprotocol = await unauthenticated_websocket_communicator.connect()
    assert subprotocol == 3000  # subprotocol 3000 is Unauthorised
    assert connected is False
```

This test passes when i test it by itself from the cli using `pytest -k test_unauthenticated_cant_connect_to_websocket`

but fails when i use `pytest` from the cli

my consumer connect function is as follows:

```
async def websocket_connect(self, event: dict) -> None:
    if self.scope["user"].is_anonymous:
        await self.close(code=3000)
    else:
        await self.accept()
```

I have a number of other async tests with similar types of code but they all pass.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I fixed the issue by adding a `@pytest.mark.django_db` decorator to the test.